# How add/change password for RSA priv key using PyCrypto

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

maybe somebody be able to help me.
I'm using PyCrypto to generate a pair of RSA keys. The public key and
private key.
I try to add/change a password to the private key, and I do not know how to
do it.

This is a piece of my code.

```
#encoding:utf-8
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

pass_alice='ala'
private_alice_key = RSA.generate(1024)
public_alice_key  = private_alice_key.publickey()

str_priv = private_alice_key.exportKey()
str_pub  = public_alice_key.exportKey()

print str_priv
print str_pub

# HOW ADD OR CHANGE PASSWORD FOR private_alice_key
```

In M2Crypt the function generate pair key RSA.gen_key take give function callback argument and I can return my own password.

```
#example in M2Crypt:
from M2Crypto import RSA
key = RSA.gen_key(1024, 6528, lambda pass:'my_password')
```

How to do it in PyCrypto.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979358/pycrypto-generate-rsa-key-protected-with-des3-password

Answer (score 2):

PyCrypto has no function, which can manage RSA passphrase.

Instead, You can use **ezPyCrypto** ([homepage](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/ezPyCrypto/)) module, which is built top of PyCrypto module. It has simpler interface and lets you:

- Generate, export and import public and private keys
- Encrypt and decrypt strings with ease
- Optionally create encrypted data as email-friendly text
- Sign and verify strings (incl. documents)
- **Protect your private key with a passphrase**
- Create 'streams', for sending data through secured sockets
- Choose any public key size you like (2048-bit recommended)
- Choose between RSA and ElGamal for public key, and IDEA, DES3, Blowfish, ARC4, IDEA for session key
- Rest in the comfort of security, with 256-bit session keys and defences against common RSA and ElGamal attacks, which will painfully frustrate anyone seeking to violate your privacy.

**Usage:**

```
"""
example7.py
Demonstrate the use of passphrases with private keys
"""
import ezPyCrypto

mysecret = "Don't look at this!!!"
raw = "Here is a string to encrypt"

# Create a key object
k = ezPyCrypto.key(passphrase=mysecret)

# Export public/private key
publicAndPrivateKey = k.exportKeyPrivate()

# Encrypt against this keypair
enc = k.encString(raw)

# Create a new key object, and import keys (with passphrase)
k1 = ezPyCrypto.key(publicAndPrivateKey, passphrase=mysecret)

# Decrypt text
dec = k.decString(enc)

# test
if dec == raw:
    print "Successful decryption using correct passphrase"
else:
    print "Failed somewhere"

print "Trying now with a bad passphrase"
try:
    k2 = ezPyCrypto.key(publicAndPrivateKey, passphrase="cracking attempt")
except ezPyCrypto.CryptoKeyError:
    print "Oops - our feeble cracking attempt failed (which is a good thing)."
else:
    print "Cracking attempt succeeded - we're not safe"
    # We're in - let's plunder
    dec2 = k2.decString(enc)
```

**Build it**

If you look into ezCryptoPy source,then you'll see key is actually encrypted/decrypted by using BlueFish algorithm:

```
   # decrypt against passphrase
        blksiz = 8 # lazy of me

        # create temporary symmetric cipher object for passphrase - 
        #hardwire to Blowfish
        ppCipher = Blowfish.new(passphrase,
                                Blowfish.MODE_CFB,
                                self._passIV[0:blksiz])
        enclen = len(keyobj)
        decpriv = ''
        i = 0
        while i < enclen:
            decbit = ppCipher.decrypt(keyobj[i:i+blksiz])
            decpriv += decbit
            i += blksiz
        keyobj = decpriv[0:size]
```

That means, you can write your own passphrase handler by using previous code example without installing ezPyCrypto. Here can you find many code examples, how do to it yourself:
[Nullege code search](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA)

**My first and alternative solution:**

You can use python *exec()* function and commandline function "ssh-keygen"([doc](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/#passwd)):

`ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]`.

Comment: Seems that the link to the ezPyCrypto now redirects to some delicious Spam.

Comment: Good catch, i just updated it; I think this answer should regarded as out-of-date anyway as it was first responded in 2011, soon almost 7years ago and there should be much better libraries now;

Answer (score 1):

For loading key with phrase look at [description of Module RSA](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html)

> ### Description of importKey
>
> `importKey(externKey, passphrase=None)`
>
> Import an RSA key (public or private half), encoded in standard form.
>
> See RSAImplementation.importKey.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - **externKey** (string) - The RSA key to import, encoded as a string.
>
>   An RSA public key can be in any of the following formats:
>
>   - X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
>   - PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
>   - OpenSSH (textual public key only)
>
>   An RSA private key can be in any of the following formats:
>
>   - PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
>   - PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE (binary or PEM encoding)
>   - OpenSSH (textual public key only)
>
>   For details about the PEM encoding, see RFC1421/RFC1423.
>
>   In case of PEM encoding, the private key can be encrypted with DES or 3TDES according to a certain pass phrase. Only OpenSSL-compatible pass phrases are supported.
> - **passphrase** (string) - In case of an encrypted PEM key, this is the pass phrase from which the encryption key is derived.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> An RSA key object (_RSAobj).
>
> #### Raises:
>
> - **ValueError/IndexError/TypeError** - When the given key cannot be parsed (possibly because the pass phrase is wrong).

Example:

```
from Crypto import RSA

key = RSA.generate(1024)
exportedKey = key.exportKey('PEM', 'my secret', pkcs=1)
```

For saving key with phrase look at [description of object _RSAobj](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html).

> ### Description of exportKey
>
> `exportKey(self, format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=1)`
>
> Export this RSA key.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - **format** (string) - The format to use for wrapping the key.
>
>   - 'DER'. Binary encoding, always unencrypted.
>   - 'PEM'. Textual encoding, done according to RFC1421/RFC1423. Unencrypted (default) or > encrypted.
>   - 'OpenSSH'. Textual encoding, done according to OpenSSH specification. Only suitable for  public keys (not private keys).
> - **passphrase** (string) - In case of PEM, the pass phrase to derive the encryption key from.
> - **pkcs** (integer) - The PKCS standard to follow for assembling the key. You have two choices:
>
>   - with 1, the public key is embedded into an X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE. The private key is embedded into a PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey DER SEQUENCE. This mode is the default.
>   - with 8, the private key is embedded into a PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE. This mode is not available for public keys.
>       PKCS standards are not relevant for the OpenSSH format.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> A byte string with the encoded public or private half.
>
> #### Raises:
>
> - **ValueError** - When the format is unknown.

Example:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

with open("key.pem", "r") as privatekey:
    encryptor = RSA.importKey(privatekey, passphrase="my secret")
```