# PyCrypto: Generate RSA key protected with DES3 password

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, des, pycrypto

I have been able to create a RSA key protected by password with DES3 (well... *I think* because I'm very new to this encryption world) by using the command:

```
openssl genrsa -out "/tmp/myKey.pem" -passout pass:"f00bar" -des3 2048
```

Now, I would like to do that inside a Python script, using PyCrypto, if possible. I have seen [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897899/how-add-change-password-for-rsa-priv-key-using-pycrypto), which seems to discourage the use of PyCrypto to do that. Is it still like that?

Of course I can always call `os.execute`, and execute the above command, but I'd consider that "cheating" **:-)**. I'm pretty much doing this to learn PyCrypto.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from PyCrypto 2.5 you can export an RSA private key and have it protected under a passphrase. A Triple DES key is internally derived from the passphrase and used to perform the actual encryption.

For instance:

```
from Crypto import RSA
from Crypto import Random

random_generator = Random.new().read
key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
exportedKey = key.exportKey('PEM', 'my secret', pkcs=1)
```

The variable `exportedKey` contains an ASCII version (PEM) of the key, encoded according to PKCS#1 (a cryptographic standard. Another option is `pkcs=8` for - guess what - PKCS#8). Since the result is standard, you can use it with several other programs, including openssl.
And of course, you can also re-import it back into python via PyCrypto!

The `exportKey` method is documented [here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey).

Comment: Working like a charm! I got almost the same output than with the openssl command: Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,F7149C8E62E0854B

4fUV/FmaMmL7qZH83+ocigFy [...]

Comment: Just to make I understand, that means that the command exportedKey = key.exportKey('PEM', 'my secret', pkcs=1), generates RSA keys from the password 'my secret'? Does 'PEM' and pkcs have security implications?

Comment: The RSA key is created when the method `generate` is called. The method `export` takes it and encodes it in PEM format. PEM and PKCS formats don't have evident (to me) security weaknesses. The interesting bit is how the 3DES key is derived from the password: that mimics `openssl`, which uses a quite outdated algorithm.