# Generate RSA public and private key pair from a passpharse

Tags: python, rsa

I want to generate a RSA key-pair from a passphrase. How can I do that in Python. I have try PBDFK2 but i works only for symmetric encryption like AES.

Answer (score 0):

[You could try using ezPyCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897899/how-add-change-password-for-rsa-priv-key-using-pycrypto):

```
import ezPyCrypto

mysecret = "Secret"
raw = "String to Encrypt"

# Create a key object
k = ezPyCrypto.key(passphrase=mysecret)

# Export public/private key
publicAndPrivateKey = k.exportKeyPrivate()

# Encrypt against this keypair
enc = k.encString(raw)

# Create a new key object, and import keys (with passphrase)
k1 = ezPyCrypto.key(publicAndPrivateKey, passphrase=mysecret)

# Decrypt text
dec = k.decString(enc)
```

Or you can use the [`exec()` function](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) and commandline function ["ssh-keygen"](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/#passwd).